# apache rewrite, how to ignore subdirectories and pass to handler

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

in virtual host environment, wish to use a handler.  for specified directories, eg, `images, script`, want `Apache` to handle it.  for all other subdirectories, wish to pass to handler.

everything is working except the last requirement

NOTE: THE FOLLOWING CODE HAS BEEN CORRECTED AND IS WORKING

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.1.12:80>

  DocumentRoot /var/www
  RewriteEngine On
  ServerName monitor.phiddler.nit:80
  UseCanonicalName Off

  # for robots
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.
  RewriteRule \.(php|php3|cgi|asp|aspx|jsp|cf|java|do|inc)$ /var/www [N,L]

  # regular subdirs
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} monitor.phiddler.nit
  RewriteRule ^/(css|image|script|admin|ckeditor)/(.*) /data/phiddler/http/$1/$2 [L]

  # ico file is in image
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} monitor.phiddler.nit
  RewriteRule \.ico$  /data/phiddler/http/image/$1.ico [L]

  # name beginning with "." rerouted to ajax handler
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} monitor.phiddler.nit
  RewriteRule /\. /data/phiddler/http/ajax.php [L,QSA]

  # all else goes to handler
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} monitor.phiddler.nit
  RewriteRule . /data/phiddler/http/handler.php [L]

</VirtualHost>
```

this should be easy, but somehow I'm missing it

also, is the `RewriteCond` necessary before each `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have fixed it in the question itself in order to serve as a correct reference

the way the question was asked and code layout was not conducive to good answers